# Firebase Android Load multiple image array to ImageView from storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a Firebase app. Without picasso i want to load images. I found the next solution:

```
    StorageReference ref =   FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("gs://fir-loadimage.appspot.com").child("myimage/rslogo.png");


    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    Glide.with(this).using(new FirebaseImageLoader()).load(ref).into(iv);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question now?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: image not load multiple

Comment: only one image load

Comment: my question is set multiple image in RecyclerView